# Are documents really 'returned in descending order of the order ID'?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search-api

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/scoreddocumentclass).

However, it doesn't actually appear to be the case. For example, here is a list of `order_id` properties I sent to the log while iterating through a list of `ScoredDocuments` returned by a search query:

```
62083050
62083026
62083044
62083032
62083043
62083057
62083055
62083013
62083049
62083047
```

I am using SDK 1.7.3.

Comment: as per the docs: "If not specified, the number of seconds since 1st Jan 2011 is used" sooooo that may be your case?

Comment: right. I see. order_id is something the user specifies when he/her puts a document in the index. thanks.

Comment: but, I still don't understand why they're not sorted. "If not specified, the number of seconds since 1st Jan 2011 is used". 'Used' presumably means, 'used for the order_id'.Then it says "Documents are returned in descending order of the order ID." So the list in my question should be sorted in descending order, no?

Comment: they use, per default, the number of seconds passed from 1st jan 2k11 to the datetime of the post --> they basically sort them on posting time, descending order... OR you specify your order_id and so on

Comment: yes, that's how I understand it should work. but it isn't actually sorted in descending order when I iterate through some results.